# Failed to retrieve directory listing: Cpanel

Tags: cpanel

I'm using Windows XP, filezilla, and using port: 6497
I can't retrieve my directories. My computer firewall is already turned off.
This is the error:

```
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (69,174,254,156,102,70)
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The above iptables command didn't work on my cpanel, the below did..

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 30000:50000 -j ACCEPT
```

and then doing

```
 iptables-save
```

to save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Open the passive ports in server firewall.

Un-comment below lines in /etc/pure-ftpd.conf

```
PassivePortRange          30000 50000
```

The open the port in server firewall. If you have CSF then you will have to add 30000:50000 in TCP_IN settings in csf configuration file. If you server just has IPTABLES then run the below command

```
iptables -INPUT -p tcp --dport 30000:50000 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of my own research, nothing seemed to work. When looking under my iptables rules I noticed no packets were captured by my original rule of:

```
    iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 30000:50000 -j ACCEPT
```

That's the rule everyone says to use to resolve this issue, unfortunately it didn't work for me. That is when I noticed the chain called "cP-Firewall-1-INPUT". Bam! I added the rule under that chain and SUCCESS!

**Solution:** (If you have a chain named "**cP-Firewall-1-INPUT**"

**Step 1:**
Un-comment below lines in /etc/pure-ftpd.conf

```
    PassivePortRange          30000 50000
```

**Step 2:** Allow the port range in iptables

```
    iptables -A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp --dport 30000:50000 -j ACCEPT
```

**Step3:** Then save your changes:

```
    iptables-save
```